# Python - No JSON can be decoded

Tags: python, json, parsing

I get an error about my JSON not being decoded.

JSON output from endpoint:

```
{"id":"16","otherid":"43sfd","happened":"2020-09-11"},{"id":"23","idd":"otherid","happened":"2020-09-10"},{"id":"12","otherid":"4543","happened":"2020-09-10"},
```

My code:

```
url = "endpoint url goes here"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
r = json.loads(response.text)
columns = r
rows_list = r["id"]
headers = []
for column in columns.keys():
    headers.append(column)
```

Error:

```
Script is Invalid, Exception: { "stackTrace": [ [ "/var/task/customconnect7343017969486770267.py", 7, "py", "r = json.loads(response.text)" ], [ "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", 338, "loads", "return _default_decoder.decode(s)" ], [ "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", 363, "decode", "obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())" ], [ "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", 381, "raw_decode", "raise ValueError(\"No JSON object could be decoded\")" ] ], "errorType": "ValueError", "errorMessage": "No JSON object could be decoded" }Run Log:
```

The way I am parsing the json may be wrong. How do I fix this? Or is my JSON output wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: did you tried with `json.loads(response.json())`?

Comment: What you have shown is not valid JSON. It is of the form ``a, b, c,``, but JSON is ``[a, b, c]`` (note the brackets and lack of trailing comma). Please check whether the endpoint actually claims to provide JSON, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a wrong JSON array (`{},{},{},`):

- it's missing the brackets around (`[]`)
- JSON does not allow a trailing comma (even though both Python and JavaScript allow a list/array like `[1,2,]`, it's not valid for JSON)

So it should be `[{"id":"16","otherid":"43sfd","happened":"2020-09-11"},{"id":"23","idd":"otherid","happened":"2020-09-10"},{"id":"12","otherid":"4543","happened":"2020-09-10"}]`, and then it works:

> ```
> >>> import json
> >>> json.loads('[{"id":"16","otherid":"43sfd","happened":"2020-09-11"},{"id":"23","idd":"otherid","happened":"2020-09-10"},{"id":"12","otherid":"4543","happened":"2020-09-10"}]')
> [{'id': '16', 'otherid': '43sfd', 'happened': '2020-09-11'}, {'id': '23', 'idd': 'otherid', 'happened': '2020-09-10'}, {'id': '12', 'otherid': '4543', 'happened': '2020-09-10'}]
> ```

I would suggest fixing the endpoint so it returns a valid JSON. But if you really want to, of course you can fix it on the Python side with some string operations.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the server is a JSON. you can use:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url).json()
```

It will return you a dictionary directly, assuming of course that the request was successful. You should probably validate the `status_code` first.

Comment: how do you know this is the issue?

Comment: @deadshot Without full stack trace and given the error in his log, it seems like using the `json()` method would either fix the issue for him or will let him know that the problem is with the response itself rather than trying to find it's origin.